# Extract certain strings and distribute them to adjacent columns

Tags: sql, regex, plsql, oracle11gr2

I have a table similar to this:

```
with tab as(
select 'P710345,P345123 are not valid' m from dual
union all
select 'P901236,P234098,P675001 are not valid' m from dual)
select * from tab
```

What I need is to extract strings beginning with `P` and place these strings into new columns in the same row.

Final result:

```
P710345,P345123 are not valid         | P710345 | P345123 |        |
P901236,P234098,P675001 are not valid | P901236 | P234098 |P675001 |
```

I have tried to extract with `regexp_substr`:

```
with tab as(
select 'P710345,P345123 are not valid' m from dual
union all
select 'P901236,P234098,P675001 are not valid' m from dual )
select regexp_substr (m,'P\d\w+','2') b from tab
```

I'm currently stuck here.

Comment: Store multiple values in one column is bad database design, the best thing would be to change the design, but if it isn't posible, I'l see if i can write some SQL to help

Comment: thanks. database design is given at the moment. as it is not a production database, it is currently acceptable, i suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest workaround i found was making a csv and then import it or use it in a speedsheet program

```
SELECT CONCAT(
  "'", m, "';'", 
  REPLACE(
     SUBSTR(m, 1, POSITION(' ' IN m)), 
     ',', 
     "';'"), 
  "';") 
FROM ( SELECT 'P710345,P345123 are not valid' AS m FROM DUAL UNION ALL SELECT 'P901236,P234098,P675001 are not valid' AS m FROM DUAL) AS t;
```

Comment: Is there a POSITION function in Oracle?

Comment: Oracle have cool funktions like regexp_substr but not Position/Lokation? I'm a mysql user :-) got here when looking for regexp questions. just use any other funktion to cut of the text at the space